# Save images inside webview Android SDK

Tags: android

Im making a simple app for some friends to use on there android phone that shows my website with images. Im using a webview to show the website inside the app. I want the users, to be able to save the actual image. Either by Hold down on the image or actually clicking a button. Been looking around on googles docs ands cant seem to find anything for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't actually played around with this yet, but from the docs it appears you have at least two (non-deprecated) options:

1. [`getHitTestResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#getHitTestResult%28%29)
2. [`requestImageRef(Message msg)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#requestImageRef%28android.os.Message%29)

According to the documentation you can use the first option to test for `IMAGE_TYPE` as result, and a url to the image is provided as well:

> If a HTML::img tag is found, the HitTestResult type is set to
>   IMAGE_TYPE and the url is set in the "extra" field.

The second option will give you a similar result:

> Request the url of the image last touched by the user. msg will be
>   sent to its target with a String representing the url as its object.

Not sure if these options are compatible with a 'long click' too though.

Alternatively, how did you have in mind to link clicking a button to a specific image? Depending on your solution for this, you may also be able to simply capture all loaded image resources using [`onLoadResource(WebView view, String url)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html#onLoadResource%28android.webkit.WebView,%20java.lang.String%29), build a list of image references and download the one that button click refers too.

Comment: About the button, on the actual website it shows only 1 image and then you click that image to show the next one. So I would want the button to download the image on the page at the moment.